# Different integral when used with assumptions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I want to calculate an integral, but Mathematica gives me different results if I am more specific with the `Assumptions` option of `Integrate`.

I have :

```
Integrate[(1 - Cos[x])/x^2 Exp[I t x], {x, -∞, ∞}]
```

that returns :

```
ConditionalExpression[π - π Abs[t], -1 < Re[t] < 1 && Im[t] == 0]
```

and :

```
Integrate[(1 - Cos[x])/x^2 Exp[I t x], {x, -∞, ∞}, Assumptions :> t ∈ Reals]
```

that returns :

```
1/2 π (Abs[-1 + t] - 2 Abs[t] + Abs[1 + t])
```

How to explain the difference between the two results ?

Comment: I would say it's a bug that there is not every conditional in the first result. But the results are the same if you assume this condition.

Answer (score 1):

The second one is more general:

```
Simplify[1/2 π (Abs[-1 + t] - 2 Abs[t] + Abs[1 + t]), -1 < t < 1]
```

> ```
> π - π Abs[t]
> ```

```
Plot[{π - π Abs[t], 1/2 π (Abs[-1 + t] - 2 Abs[t] + Abs[1 + t])}, {t, -3, 3}, 
     BaseStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

Comment: Try `Integrate[(1 - Cos[x])/x^2 Exp[I 2 x], {x, -∞, ∞}]`

Comment: @belisarius It returns 0 as expected. See red line in the plot.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still don't understand why the first one (which should be more general, as there is no `Assumptions`) does not give a complete result. Is it a bug ?